# Why did Yoda not take on another apprentice after Episode III?

Tags: jedi, star-wars, jedi-training

At the end of Episode III (or shortly after) the movie storyline implies that Yoda goes into hiding on Dagobah.

Knowing that he was one of the few remaining Jedi why did he not attempt to find an apprentice during the years that the Skywalker twins were growing up instead of waiting on Dagobah? Was he simply waiting all that time for Luke Skywalker to grow up and come to him for training?

It seems hard to believe that there were no other viable candidates for Jedi training in the entire galaxy. So why did he effectively waste those years to Imperial rule?

Even if he had the foresight to know that Luke Skywalker would come to him, surely he could have passed on some Jedi training to others in the (approximately) 20 years that pass between episodes III and IV.

Comment: Yeah, he could have just searched the huge population of Dagobah for a force-sensitive youngling!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

G-canon confirms the "Even if he had foresight to know that Luke Skywalker would come to him" part of your question - that was what Yoda planned (or trusted the Force) to do. Based on Matthew Stover's novelization of Episode III (ROTS):

> "... Hidden, safe, the children must be kept. **Foundation of the
>   new Jedi Order, they will be**."
>   "We should split them up," Obi-Wan said. "Even if the Sith find
>   one, the other may survive. I can take the boy, Master Yoda, and you
>   take the girl. We can hide them away, keep them safe— train them
>   as Anakin should have been trained—"
>   ... **When right is the time for skills to be taught, to us the living Force will
>   bring them. Until then, wait we will, and watch, and learn."**

Answer (score 11):

**G-Canon**

Yoda was living in hiding/exile during the years between episodes 3 and 5. How is he supposed to find a new padawan to train without revealing his location to the Empire? Dagobah had been erased from the archives as having ever existed. The last thing he wants to do is bring attention to himself or the world by word getting out that he is there.

**C-Canon**

He met with Starkiller (the clone of Galen Marek) as well as Tash Arranda and Zak Arranda. Starkiller was not looking for a teacher, but Tash and Zak were.

From [wookieepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Dagobah):

> Tash Arranda and Zak Arranda met Yoda on the planet, but he chose not to train them in the Jedi ways at that time, explaining to them he was awaiting a different student.

Comment: Wow.. I liked the C-Canon. :)

Comment: What you think the only little green muppet in the universe cant go wandering around the galaxy with out getting noticed just because he is a little famous?

Answer (score 1):

Yoda knew that Palpatine was simply TOO powerful for any Jedi other than someone with the same midi-chlorian count as Anakin, to take on.

Yoda had to wait for Luke to grow up and for the force to create the circumstances necessary to bring Luke to him for training, when the time is right. Training any other Jedi would have been a waste of time. He also knew that there were several dozen to perhaps a hundred or so Jedi that survived order 66, but that they were told to go into hiding, abandon being a Jedi and live as normal a life as possible.

Yoda had no way to search out for new Jedi students while he is in exile on such a remote planet as Dagobah. The other reason that Yoda picked Dagobah is because he had once fought a very powerful dark Jedi on the planet and defeated him there. That is the source of the poweful concentration of dark side energy in the cave where Luke failed and such the vision of Darth Vader that ended up being Luke himself.

When Yoda killed the dark Jedi, the explosion of dark side energy infected the cave, which is why Yoda brought him there as a test.

Yoda's small hut was only a short distance from that dark side cave.. this was not by accident at all. Yoda specifically put his house there because he knew that with such a strong nexus of dark side energy there, it would hide his powerful light side force signature from being picked up by Palpatine or Vader.

Luke later surmized that it was like a positive and negative charge that cancel each other out and this was a major reason why Yoda was able to stay completely hidden from Palpatine the entire time. That, along with his natural ability to hide in the force as well.